# Uvicorn: Attribute "app" not found in module "app.app"

Tags: python, uvicorn

I'm trying to follow a [basic guide](https://youtu.be/62pP9pfzNRs) to begin using FastAPI and uvicorn. I followed steps in the video, and wrote the same code(And file structure is the same, app.py in app folder, main.py in outer folder)

main.py

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("app.app:app", port=8000, reload=True)
```

app.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", tags=['ROOT'])
async def root() -> dict:
    return{"Ping":"Pong"}
```

Launching main.py results in the following error:

```
Error loading ASGI app. Attribute "app" not found in module "app.app".
```

I've tried renaming `app.py` file and launching it directly from command line using `uvicorn` but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start `uvicorn` with `app:app`. The file name is already declared in the first part of `app:app`.

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("app:app", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Also, you could run `uvicorn` from your terminal like so:

```
uvicorn app:app --port 8000 --reload
```